# Create a count in count in sql select

Tags: mysql

I have a question: it's possible to create an count in count in sql:
my code is:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT p.id_participant ) as number
                       FROM participation p
                       INNER JOIN message m ON m.id_participation=p.id             
                       AND p.id_event = 4
```

I want to add in first count another count from table winners with count (id_winner)
Help me please, Exist a solution?

Comment: Please, provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the aggregate function **SUM**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT SUM(val)
  2  FROM  (SELECT Count(*) VAL
  3         FROM   emp
  4         UNION
  5         SELECT Count(*) VAL
  6         FROM   dept);

  SUM(VAL)
----------
        18
```

Comment: I got an error: every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Please show what you did, just like I did. Copy paste the SQL*Plus session.